# Scroll en aside css

Tags: html, css, bulma

Estoy haciendo la maquetación de una página web, que debería tener un aparte con su respectivo menú, el problema es que no puedo hacer que se desplace, ya que tendrá varios menús y submenús.

Estoy usando el marco BLUMA y el SCSS.

Para explicarme mejor, lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que si el aparte tiene varios menús por los que puedo desplazarme sin mover el ID="PAGE-CONTENT" el contenido de la página es otro pergamino.

Prácticamente estoy haciendo un panel de administración

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap");
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: .9rem;
}

.navbar {
  border-top: 3px solid #83589c;
}

#app-header .navbar-brand {
  background-color: #282a3c;
}

#app-header .navbar-brand .navbar-item h4 {
  color: #cccccc;
}

#app-header .navbar-menu {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #777777;
          box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #777777;
}

#app-content {
  background: #F2F3F8;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#app-content #navigation {
  background: #292C3A;
}

#app-content #navigation .menu {
  font-size: .9rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#app-content #navigation p.menu-label {
  color: #868aa8;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#app-content #navigation li a {
  color: #868aa8;
  padding: 9px 40px;
}

#app-content #navigation li a.is-active {
  color: #8D68AB;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#app-content #navigation a:hover {
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  background-color: #2C2F3D;
}
```

--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
      <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <!------------------------------------------------------------------->
          <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bulma.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jumboStyle.css">
          <title>Cristian Garcia</title>
      </head>

      <body class="has-navbar-fixed-top">

        <!-- navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar columns is-fixed-top is-marginless" id="app-header" role="navigation"
            aria-label="main navigation">
            <div class="navbar-brand column is-2">
                <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
                    <h4 class="title is-5">CRISTIAN ADMIN</h4>
                </a>

                <a role="button" class="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false"
                    data-target="navbarBasicExample">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-menu" id="navbarBasicExample">
                <div class="navbar-start">
                    <a href="" class="navbar-item">welcome</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- navigation and content -->
        <div class="columns is-marginless" id="app-content">
            <div class="column is-2 is-fullheight is-paddingless" id="navigation">
                <!-- aside -->
                <aside class="menu">
                    <p class="menu-label">
                        General
                    </p>
                    <ul class="menu-list">
                        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a>Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a>Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a>Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a>Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a>Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a>Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a>Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a>Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a>Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a>Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a>Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a>Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a>Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a>Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a>Customers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-10" id="page-content">
                <div class="content">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, maxime dolorem commodi,
                        aspernatur, ratione quaerat tenetur itaque tempore aut nulla quas aperiam eos error nobis culpa
                        labore iure cupiditate. Saepe.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, maxime dolorem commodi,
                        aspernatur, ratione quaerat tenetur itaque tempore aut nulla quas aperiam eos error nobis culpa
                        labore iure cupiditate. Saepe.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, maxime dolorem commodi,
                        aspernatur, ratione quaerat tenetur itaque tempore aut nulla quas aperiam eos error nobis culpa
                        labore iure cupiditate. Saepe.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, maxime dolorem commodi,
                        aspernatur, ratione quaerat tenetur itaque tempore aut nulla quas aperiam eos error nobis culpa
                        labore iure cupiditate. Saepe.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, maxime dolorem commodi,
                        aspernatur, ratione quaerat tenetur itaque tempore aut nulla quas aperiam eos error nobis culpa
                        labore iure cupiditate. Saepe.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, maxime dolorem commodi,
                        aspernatur, ratione quaerat tenetur itaque tempore aut nulla quas aperiam eos error nobis culpa
                        labore iure cupiditate. Saepe.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, maxime dolorem commodi,
                        aspernatur, ratione quaerat tenetur itaque tempore aut nulla quas aperiam eos error nobis culpa
                        labore iure cupiditate. Saepe.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, maxime dolorem commodi,
                        aspernatur, ratione quaerat tenetur itaque tempore aut nulla quas aperiam eos error nobis culpa
                        labore iure cupiditate. Saepe.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jumboQuery.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```